# NSWindow levels and modal dialogs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an application that needs to display a window on top of anythings else. To achieve this I call `[window setLevel:NSStatusWindowLevel]` on my main window.

This works fine except that I can't use any modal dialogs or alerts from this window. The problem seems to be that `[NSWindow beginSheet...]` internally calls `setLevel:` on the target modal window with a value lower than `NSStatusWindowLevel`, so the modal dialog is displayed **behind** its parent window. The same happens when using an NSAlert from a window with higher window level, the alert is displayed behind.

The only [ugly] workaround I found is to inherit NSWindow, override `setLevel:` and prevent setting a lower level value on these modal windows but this only works when I have control over the window and doesn't work for NSAlerts.

Is there a more elegant solution for displaying modal dialogs from a NSWindow with high window level value that will also work with NSAlerts? Or I will be unable to use NSAlert with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one thing that comes to mind is to check if `NSAlert` uses a special `NSWindow` subclass you could make a category on it and hook the `setLevel:` method via swizzling ([here is an example](http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/method-swizzling) of extending an existing method via swizzling). there is nothing stopping you from doing this in a plain `NSWindow` subclass either.

I know its not the "elegant solution" you'd hoped for, but its the only one I know off the top of my head. I suppose it is slightly more elegant in that you don't have to insert your custom subclass everywhere throughout your program, but less elegant in that you are messing with the objective-c runtime using code that simply seems wrong.

Comment: I ended up doing just this. Created a category on NSWindow to add a "swizzle setLevel" method that will swizzle (using the JRSwizzle library) NSWindow's setLevel and added a "isLevelLocked" property. In my swizzled method I check whether the window's level is locked and if it is, prevent setting a new level. Works well. Although it annoys me that I have to do this. Guess it's yet another oversight I keep finding throughout the Cocoa API.